# Solving for $0$ with x and y in the exponents

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have the question where I am to find the critical points for an equation $f(x,y)$. 
I already calculated the partial fraction of $x$
 $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} = ye^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}-2x^{2}ye^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}$$ 
and the partial fraction of $y$ 
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial y} = xe^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}-2y^{2}xe^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}$$

Since both $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ need to equal $0$, I would normally solve with substitution. But due to the nature of the equation having exponents for $e$ I do not know how to solve for the answer. When I isolated all I could come up with was the coordinate $(0,0)$.

Comment: Since $e^u \neq 0$ for all $u$, whether $u$ includes two variables or not, you can always divide by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first line, we have $ye^{-x^2-y^2}(1-2x^2)=0$ since $e^x$ is never zero, we must have that either $y=0$ or $1-2x^2=0$. Take $y=0$ and substitute into the second equation, then $x=0$. Now take $x=\frac {1}{\sqrt 2}$ and the second equation becomes $\frac {1}{\sqrt 2}e^{-x^2-y^2}(1-2y^2)=0$ meaning (again because $e^x$ and $\frac {1}{\sqrt 2}$ are never zero) that $1-2y^2=0$. Repeat the argument with $-\frac {1}{\sqrt 2}$. Then we obtain that the zeroes are $(0,0)$, $(\pm \frac {1}{\sqrt 2},\pm\frac {1}{\sqrt 2})$.